# Needing to use if statement in multiplying a vector: vectorisation

Tags: matlab

I have a vector

```
V=[ 1 2 3 5 9];
```

and would like to multiply it like this:

```
newVect=zeros(1,length(V));

for i=1:length(V)

    if V(i)==1
       newVect(i)=V(i)*somevaluex
    elseif V(i)==5
       newVect(i)=V(i)*somevaluey
    else
       newVect(i)=V(i);
end
```

This seems cumbersome as I'm actually dealing with arrays with 10000 elements. Can this be replaced by vectorisation somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that:

```
newVect = V .* (   someValuex.*(V==1) +  someValuey.*(V==5) + V.*( (V~=1) & (V~=5) ) )
```

or a bit faster:

```
newVect=V;
newVect(V==1)=V(V==1)*someValuex;
newVect(V==5)=V(V==5)*someValuey;
```

Comment: Ah! very nice, thank you :)!  if V was a large matrix (r=100000, c=100) does this have to be done row by row within a for loop? or can it be done in a similar way to above?

Comment: If `V` is a matrix the first example will work for sure. The second may change the shape of `V`. The easier is that you try it yourself.

Comment: Ah, i've noticed that if someValuex=rand; then this `rand` value remains the same throughout... and I would like it to change. What do you think? ie. `newVect = V .* (   rand.*(V==1) +  someValuey.*(V==5) + V.*( (V~=1) & (V~=5) ) )`

Comment: You should replace `rand` by `rand(size(V))`